# taskkill window with space and quotation on its name?

Tags: windows, cmd, taskkill

How do to kill a cmd window with space and quotation on its name?
I want to kill a window that its name is: Remote /C comupterName "session1"

```
taskkill /f /fi "WindowTiltle eq Remote /C comupterName "session1""
```

doesn't work, it don't find the window
Thanks

Comment: Is that the name of the process? can you copy paste the name from running `tasklist`

Comment: The name of the process is remote.exe. But it solved, juste add double quotation like this: taskkill /f /fi "WindowTiltle eq Remote /C comupterName ""session1""". Thanks @Adil H

Comment: I kinda thought that would be the answer but did not want to offer it without testing. Although using 'imagename' = process name would be probably easier, if you had multiple and you just wanted to kill one, then you would use the method you used.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple windows where the process is remote.exe, because I many session: Remote /C comupterName "sessionN", where N is integer, and I went to kill a specific window. I have tested and it works.

Comment: you can put your solution as answer below and then mark it as answer. That way, people looking for similar answer can find it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, juste add double quotation:

```
taskkill /f /fi "WindowTiltle eq Remote /C comupterName ""session1"""
```